# Is it possible to control the size of log file?

Tags: ros, roscpp, rosconsole

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I code a very simple CPP node which spam rosout with a lot of ROS_INFO :

```
ros::Rate r(100.0);
std::string logLine;
for(int i = 0 ; i < 1024 ; ++i)
{
    logLine.append("abcd ");
}

while(ros::ok())
{
    r.sleep();
    ROS_INFO_STREAM(logLine);
}
```

When I launch this node, I can see both log files "rosout.log" and "my_node_name-stdout.log" growing. When "rosout.log" is around 100Mo, the file is "rolled". A new file called rosout.log.1 is created, an rosout.log continue to be feeded with the ROS_INFO...

Look in the source code of rosout, I understand that this size is [hard coded](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/indigo-devel/tools/rosout/rosout.cpp#L77) to 100 Mo (this is not a problem).

The problem is with the log file of my node. This file seems to be never splitted.

**Is it possible to control the size of this log file ?**

I try to understand the rosconsole source code, and this part of the roscpp client library. I guess that writting in the log file is done thanks to Log4CXX. Is it done with a FileAppender ? If yes, where is it instanciated ?  And can we configure it in rosconsole.config ?

If I well understoud, roslaunch is responsible of redirecting stdout and stderr into log files (if the node is launched with argument output="log"). **Does roslaunch can do file rolling ?**

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200611/is-it-possible-to-control-the-size-of-log-file-?/) by [abarral](https://answers.ros.org/users/1825/abarral/) on ROS Answers with karma: 138 on 2015-01-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem is that roslaunch redirect stdout of the node subprocess to a file.

I proposed a patch [PR #551](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/551) which correct this problem. In this patch the subprocess's stdout are redirected to a "logging.logger" object. This object contain a RotatingFile Handler. This handler will natively control the size of logged data...

---

Originally posted by [abarral](https://answers.ros.org/users/1825/abarral/) with karma: 138 on 2015-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0